# UML component diagram for Python code: How to illustrate difference between classes and modules?

Tags: python, module, components, uml, diagram

I need to draw an UML component diagram for my code / a scientific paper.
My Python project consists of a few different files (modules) and also some classes.
How do you illustrate this in a UML component diagram? Do i have to use different connectors depending on the "types" of the "components"?

Let's say there are the following 'components':

1. Service (class)
2. PdfCreator (class)
3. calc_utils (module)

1 .  interacts with 2. and 3.

Comment: You're essentially asking "what is it and how does it work?" so I'd recommend that you read up a little bit. Here are some [useful](http://www.agilemodeling.com/style/componentDiagram.htm) [UML](https://sparxsystems.com/resources/tutorials/uml2/component-diagram.html) [resources](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/component-diagrams.html)

Comment: Hi till31, please try to create the UML diagram, show it, and we will give our comments.

Answer (score 1):

Basically a Python class corresponds to a UML class. A Python module can just be seen as UML component containg a set of classes. You are free to show the contained classes and/or to show interfaces with the component. Probably for Python the latter is less appropriate. You can use dependency from a class to show that it needs a module. Here you can especially utilitze «use»  relations.

[image]